# How to add a display a total value of the checkbox that are checked

Tags: javascript, html

***I'm trying to display a total value of all the checkboxes that are checked
I've tried only this solution***

my description is quite precise and self-explanatory

**Javascript function**

How to display the total of all checkboxes that are checked. Trying to display the total price by calculating all the checkboxes that are checked.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>On the go</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.scss">
  <script>
    function calcAndShowTotal() { **
      * // declaring the name and total***
      var hotbeverage = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="hotbeverage"]');
      var total = 0; **
      * // checking if any checkboxes have been selected***
      for (i = 0; i < hotbeverage.length; i++) { **
        * // if the checkbox is selected add the value to total***
        if (hotbeverage[i].checked) {
          total = total + hotbeverage[i].value;
        }

        document.getElementById("amount").value = "You order total is R" + total;
      }
  </script>
  ***// adding checkboxes***
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hot Beverages</h1>
  <div id="pricelist">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item1" price="25.00">Americano <b>R25.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item2" price="2">Caffe Latte <b>R30.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item3" price="3">Cappuccino <b>R15.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item4" price="4">Hot Chocolate<b>R20.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item5" price="5">Chai Latte <b>R20.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item6" price="6">ButterScotch latte<b>R28.00</b><br>
    <input type="text" id="amount" value="0" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**I want the text field to populate with the value**

Comment: The way you use comments is wrong.And I do not see any function call.

Comment: how would you do it

Comment: It should be starting with `<!--` and ending with `-->` for HTML and `//` for javascript

Comment: <!-- <h1>okay cool</h1>-->

Answer (score 0):

The main problem comes when you're trying to calculate the value of the input when the real value is in the `price` attribute, so you can change `.value` by `.getAttribute('price')`.

**NOTE:** It's always better to use `data-*` attribute when you need a custom attribute, so `data-price` will be more efficient, then you can get the value like :

```
parseFloat( hotbeverage[i].dataset.price );
```

```js
document.querySelector('#calc').addEventListener('click', calcAndShowTotal);

function calcAndShowTotal() {
  var hotbeverage = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="hotbeverage"]');
  var total = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < hotbeverage.length; i++) {
    if (hotbeverage[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat( hotbeverage[i].getAttribute('price') );
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("amount").value = "You order total is R " + total;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hot Beverages</h1>
<div id="pricelist">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item1" price="25.00">Americano <b>R25.00</b><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item2" price="2">Caffe Latte <b>R30.00</b><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item3" price="3">Cappuccino <b>R15.00</b><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item4" price="4">Hot Chocolate<b>R20.00</b><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item5" price="5">Chai Latte <b>R20.00</b><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item6" price="6">ButterScotch latte<b>R28.00</b><br>
  <input type="text" id="amount" value="0" />
</div>

<button id="calc">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the total of all **checkboxes** that are checked and display the total price by calculating all the **checkboxes** that are checked you can use following code:
 ***html tag:***

> test 1
>       test 2
>       test 3
>       test 4

***javaScript code:***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#pakker :checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('#pakker :checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

        $('#sum').html(sum);

    });

});
```

Please also refer following link for more details.
http://jsfiddle.net/vaKWs/6/

Comment: Be careful... there's no jQuery tag in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Following are mistakes in the code:

- You are not calling the function `calcAndShowTotal`. You should attach event to all the checkboxes to see change.
- You are adding value but you should add its `price`. Use `getAttribute` to checkbox's price.
- In your loop you are declaring global variable `i`. Use let before it.

```js
let hotbeverage = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="hotbeverage"]');

hotbeverage.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('change',calcAndShowTotal)
})


function calcAndShowTotal() { 
       // declaring the name and total***
      var total = 0; 
       // checking if any checkboxes have been selected***
      for (let i = 0; i < hotbeverage.length; i++) { 
         // if the checkbox is selected add the value to total***
      if (hotbeverage[i].checked) {
          total = total + (+hotbeverage[i].getAttribute('price'))
        }

     document.getElementById("amount").value = "You order total is R" + total;
   }
}
```

```html
  <h1>Hot Beverages</h1>
  <div id="pricelist">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item1" price="25.00">Americano <b>R25.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item2" price="2">Caffe Latte <b>R30.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item3" price="3">Cappuccino <b>R15.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item4" price="4">Hot Chocolate<b>R20.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item5" price="5">Chai Latte <b>R20.00</b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hotbeverage" value="item6" price="6">ButterScotch latte<b>R28.00</b><br>
    <input type="text" id="amount" value="0" />
  </div>
```